# Testing React Context update

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have been struggling to test a React Context update for a while. I can predefine the value of the `Context.Provider` however, the solution is not ideal because an update to the context which is supposed to happen within component utilising the context is not actually happening.

When I test this manually the text 'Account name: abc' changes to 'Account name: New account name' but not in the test. The context value remains the same.

The reason I predefine the value is because the component relies on a fetch response from a parent and I am unit testing `<ImportAccounts />` only.

In a test I am rendering a component with predefined value

```
test('accountName value is updated on click', () => {
  const { getByText, getByLabelText, getByRole } = render(
    <ImportAccountsContext.Provider value={{ accountName: { value: 'abc', setValue: jest.fn() }}}>
      <ImportAccounts />
    </ImportAccountsContext.Provider>,
  );

  expect(getByText('Account name: abc')).toBeInTheDocument();

  const input = getByLabelText('Account name');
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'New account name' } });
  fireEvent.click(getByRole('button', { name: 'Update' }));
  expect(getByText('Account name: New account name')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Here's my context

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useCallback, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

export interface StateVariable<T> {
  value: T;
  setValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>;
}

export interface ImportAccountsState {
  accountName: StateVariable<string>;
}

export const ImportAccountsContext = createContext<ImportAccountsState>(
  {} as ImportAccountsState,
);

export const ImportAccountsProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [accountName, setAccountName] = useState('');

  const initialState: ImportAccountsState = {
    accountName: {
      value: accountName,
      setValue: setAccountName,
    },
  };

  return (
    <ImportAccountsContext.Provider value={initialState}>
      {children}
    </ImportAccountsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useImportAccountsContext = () => {
  return useContext<ImportAccountsState>(ImportAccountsContext);
};
```

Import Accounts is as simple as

```
export const ImportAccounts = () => {
  const { accountName } = useImportAccountsContext();
  const [newAccountName, setNewAccountName] = useState(accountName.value);
  
  const handleAccountNameChange = () => {
    accountName.setValue(newAccountName);
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Account name: {accountName.value}</h1>
    
      <label htmlFor="accountName">Account name</label>
      <input
        value={newAccountName}
        onChange={e => setNewAccountName(e.target.value)}
        id="accountName"
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={handleAccountNameChange}>
          Update
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

How can I test that accountName has actually updated?

Comment: can you provide a bit of code from `<ImportAccounts />` where you are setting the context value?

Comment: @TomFinney I've updated the post however, ImportAccounts should not matter so much since I can see it working testing manually.

Comment: sorry if I don't understand the question - I thought you were asking how to test this  as if it was responding to the request and then your context value was updating correctly. Is this issue that in your test `'New account name'` isn't present in the next context value and the last expect fails?

Comment: Let's put the response aside. Even when it is as simple as just updating a value the context doesn't change. It remains what's been initially set `value={{ accountName: 'abc' }}` regardless of whether accountName changes. The underlying code updates the accountName in context but not in the test. So my test checking whether a value has updated fails because it remains 'abc'.

Comment: `expect(getByText('Account name: abc')).toBeInTheDocument();` does that test pass

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: `value={{ accountName: 'abc' }}`  i'm surprised it works and you don't get errors thrown trying to call `setValue` on that

Comment: Sorry, you're right, the context value is actually `{ accountName: { value: 'abc', setValue: jest.fn() }}`.

Comment: so right now what happens is your `jest.fn` will presumably have `.mock.calls` of length 1 with the argument passed in from your test `'New account name'` -> so just for fun you can move `jest.fn()` into a variable like `const mockSetName = jest.fn()` and pass it into your context provider's value and then after you trigger the event, you could log out `mockSetName.mock.calls()` just to see the underpinning stuff is working ok

Comment: for actually getting the test to pass, you would need to tweak your fake test component a bit more and so you actually change the `accountName.value` so it would trigger the content of your component to change -> looking at the code provided, I would be extremely tempted to just take your whole test component and put it another function like `function MockImportAccountsContext() { return ThatStuff}` but inside of here, replace the static object you use as the provider value with just a useState call

Answer (score 1):

If we don't need the default value for the `ImportAccounts` provider then we make the test pass easily. `ImportAccountsProvider` manages the state of the accountName within itself. In that provider, we are passing the `accountName` state of type `ImportAccountsState` to all our children through the context provider.

Now coming to your problem,

```
const { getByText, getByLabelText, getByRole } = render(
    <ImportAccountsContext.Provider value={{ accountName: { value: 'abc', setValue: jest.fn() }}}>
      <ImportAccounts />
    </ImportAccountsContext.Provider>,
  );
```

Here, the `value: 'abc'` is not a state value, it's simply a string constant 'abc' which will never be going to change. This is something that we should note. We must pass the state value to the context provider if we want to share the value with the children which is not going to be constant in the entire react lifecycle.

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

test('should update the context with existing provider', () => {
  render(
    <ImportAccountsProvider>
      <ImportAccounts />
    </ImportAccountsProvider>
  );

  // some constant hoisted to make it clean code
  const accountInput = screen.getByRole('textbox', { name: /account name/i });
  const accountInputValue = 'subrato patnaik';

  expect(accountInput).toHaveAttribute('value', '');

  // do some changes
  userEvent.type(accountInput, accountInputValue);

  //validate "changes"
  expect(screen.getByDisplayValue(accountInputValue)).toBeTruthy();
  expect(accountInput).toHaveAttribute('value', accountInputValue);

  // update context
  userEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /update/i }));

  // validate update
  expect(screen.getByRole('heading')).toHaveTextContent(/subrato/i);
  screen.debug();
});
```

Inside the ImportAccountsProvider we can do the fetch call and set the accountName state to the response of the fetch call.

```
export const ImportAccountsProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [accountName, setAccountName] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
  // do the fetch call here and update the accountName state accordingly
  });

  const initialState: ImportAccountsState = {
    accountName: {
      value: accountName,
      setValue: setAccountName,
    },
  };

  return (
    <ImportAccountsContext.Provider value={initialState}>
      {children}
    </ImportAccountsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useImportAccountsContext = () => {
  return useContext<ImportAccountsState>(ImportAccountsContext);
};
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. The problem with this is that I can't set a default value to begin with. I know this is going to update the variable because it's no longer using `jest.fn()`. My question was how to pass the initial value and then still be able to update it.

Comment: You are managing the context value in the `ImportAccountsProvider`. In the test you are using `ImportAccounts.Provider` which doesn't manage context value.

Comment: See the [video](https://youtu.be/CJVucXhyHOM) on how to test react context. He has explained the same thing in deep.